# smart pointer on field of struct

Tags: c++, boost

I have read that one must not store `std::auto_ptr` in `std::vector` and that `boost::ptr_vector` could be used instead. I have been able to do so, I don't know however how to use `ptr_vector`, when I don't want to store pointers, but a struct, which has a pointer member.

In this example, I want to open some files and store the associated `ofstream` object with some additional data, for later use. I would like to replace the `file` field of `struct data` with a smart pointer. Since the `vector<data> v` should be the owner, I think that a `shared_ptr` would work, but wouldn't be appropriate.

What should I replace the naked pointer `file` with?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct data {
  std::string filename;
  std::ofstream* file;

  data(const std::string filename, std::ofstream* file)
    : filename(filename), file(file)
  {
  }
};

std::vector<data> open_files()
{
  std::vector<data> v;
  v.push_back(data("foo", new std::ofstream("foo")));
  return v;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<data> v = open_files();

  /* use the files */
  *(v[0].file) << "foo";

  delete v[0].file;  // either rely on dtor to close(), or call it manually
}
```

**Update:**
I feel I have done a sub optimal job in describing my problem, let me try with another example. Also I am looking for a C++03 solution:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>

struct T {
  std::auto_ptr<int> a;
};

int main()
{
  // instead of
  // std::vector<std::auto_ptr<int> > v;
  // use
  boost::ptr_vector<int> v;

  // what to use instead of
  // std::vector<T> w;
}
```

Comment: Do whatever cleanup is necessary in ``data``'s destructor. Since the vector doesn't hold pointers, you have to take no action. If ``data``'s destructor is correct, everything will take care of itself.

Comment: Why do you need a (deprecated) auto_ptr? Use boost::shared_ptr<int> which is copyable. It will be owned by the vector and destroyed when the vector leaves scope.

Comment: `auto_ptr` models unique ownership, whereas `shared_ptr` has a different meaning of shared ownership. I would use `unique_ptr` if I would have access to C++11. However using `share_ptr` is probably still better than my version.

Comment: shared_ptr is reference counting so doesn't have ownership semantics. Its the copying ability that you need in order to store in a vector. Reference counting is an added bonus because you won't need to worry about deletion either.

Comment: As `std::ofstream` does not support copying, and `std::vector` is allowed to copy its contents around, your safest bet is to use `boost::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>`, even though it does not model the ownership semantics you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your data class, I would suggest using an `std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream>`. This is not to save you from an accidental memory leak, since you are deleting the pointer in the constructor, but rather to *make the ownership explicit*. A user of your code would have to know what `data` is doing with the pointer it takes in the constructor:

```
std::ofstream ofs;
{
   data d1("crash", &ofs);
} // error! d1 will attempt to delete stack allocated object

std::ofstream* pOfs = new std::ofstream(....);
data d2("crash again", pOfs);
delete pOFs; // user thinks data makes a deep copy
```

However, with `unique_ptr` the intend is clear, hence it is harder to make mistakes:

```
data d3("OK", std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream>(new std::ofstream(....)));

std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> pOfs2(new std::ofstream(....));
data d4("OK", pOfs2); // safe, pOfs's contents have been safely moved

// we can check pOfs2 after the move
if (pOfs2) { /*  */ }
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a proposal for C++98 too?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Unfortuately, there isn't a completely satisfying alternative, but you could use an `std::auto_ptr`. You would have to keep it private and avoid copying it. You should make sure you [understand the pitfalls](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm)

Comment: Since I plan to put the enclosing class into a `vector`, (and if `unique_ptr` is not available) I prefer `shared_ptr`, even though it has different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete pointer in destructor:

```
struct data 
{
  std::string filename;
  std::ofstream* file;

  data(const std::string filename, std::ofstream* file)
    : filename(filename), file(file)
  {
  }
  ~data()
  {
     delete file;
  }
};
```

Or use `std::unique_ptr` to wrap that pointer but its unnecessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an ofstream* as a member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct data {
  std::string filename;
  data(const std::string filename) : filename(filename)
  {}
};

std::vector<data> open_files()
{
  std::vector<data> v;
  v.push_back(data("foo"));
  return v;
}
```

If you want to append to the file, specify the app file mode.

```
void print_files(const std::vector<data>& v)
{
    for(std::vector<data>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::ofstream os(it->filename, std::ostream::app);
        os << "bar";
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<data> v = open_files();

    print_files(v);
}
```

Comment: I will write multiple times to different files and have therefore opend all the files in advance.